# Filtering rows with mongo $lookup and $project

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am building an app that pairs people up. You look through a list of people and either connect or dismiss the profile, one at a time.

### user model

```
//user
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String
    ...
}
```

As a user, when I want to fetch new people to connect with, I will execute a query against the `user` table.

As the user approves or denies connections with users, I create an entry in a `usermatches` collection, for each decision.

### usermatch model

```
//usermatches table
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  requester: ObjectId,
  receiver: ObjectId,
  approved: boolean
}
```

Now in future queries for people to connect with, I'll again query the `user` table.

However, I do not want to get any users, whom I share a row with in the `usermatches` table.

So when I request a list of users, by using lookup I will have collection of their requested and received matches.

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "requester",
            as: "requested_matches"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "receiver",
            as: "received_matches"
        }
    }
], (err, result) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

What I need to do is eliminate users from the query, who share a `usermatches` row with me. So I'll need to check my `_id` against the requester, or receiver `_id` values in the usermatch entry, for each one of the users, and each one of their collections.

````
var my_id = "abc123";    
User.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "requester",
            as: "requested_matches"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "receiver",
            as: "received_matches"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            ...
            //more user data
            requested_matches: {
                // I need to filter out users who contain my ```_id``` in their ```requested_matches``` or ```received_requests```.
            },
            received_matches: {
                // same here
            }    
        }
    }
], (err, result) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
});
````

How can I filter out `user` rows that contain `my_id` in their requested_matches or received_requests. i.e. `requested_matches.reciever == my_id` or `received_requests.requestor == my_id`

## Update - Solved

I did not need to use `$project` at all. All I had to do was populate those collections and then check my request.user._id

Left Joins in mongo, what a time to be alive.

```
User.aggregate([

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "requester",
            as: "requested_matches"
        }
    },

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "usermatches",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "receiver",
            as: "received_matches"
        }
    },

    {
        $match: 
          $and: [{
                    "requested_matches.receiver": {
                        "$ne": new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
                    }
                }, {
                    "received_matches.requester": {
                        "$ne": new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
                    }
                }]
    }


], (err, result) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Why are you complicating this? Simply use `$match` as the **very first stage** ( just like you always should ) and only return the current `User` by the input value to `_id`. Or are you asking to "exclude" that current user from **also** being present in the resulting arrays from `$lookup`?? Really unclear on that point.

Comment: I am looking to exclude anyone who has a user_match relationship with me. So for every user, my _id cannot exist in either their requested_matches or received_matches

Comment: So just "current user" ( which is the `_id` value ? ) cannot exist in any of the array results from `$lookup`? Right? Is this what you are asking? Which field should be fitered then? Because the fields we are doing the `$lookup` on are actually by the `_id` value

Comment: Yes, and if the _id does match any elements in those arrays I want to remove the user from return. Not just the element in the lookup collection, the entire user row.

Comment: Which field?? What does a `"usermatches"` item look like?? Which field would identify the  user from within that result??

Comment: {
  _id: ObjectId,
  requester: ObjectId,
  receiver: ObjectId
} it is also at the top of the original post.

Comment: You need to pay attention. You are **contradicting yourself**. On one hand we are doing the `$lookup` using the present `_id` from the parent to match. Now you say you do not want that value in results. So which one is it? If I return values matching `_id` to `requester`, then where are the values matching `_id` meant to be **excluded** from? from the `"usermatches"` value of `_id`, or `receiver`? Because it **cannot** be requester. I'm honestly a bit tired of going in circles on this. Take a moment and realize how unclear your question is.

Comment: I, as user_1, am executing a query on the users table. The users returned to user_1 may or may not have had a previous interaction with user_1. I do not want any users returned where there has been a previous interaction with user_1. An interaction is recorded in the usermatches table. The usermatches table is essentially a linking table for a requester and a receiver. Once its been generated, those two users can never see each other again in future queries. Thus why I want to eliminate users returned, who contain user_1's id in either of their requested or received $lookup collections.

Comment: "Future queries". Now go and have a look at your question again and see where any such thing is said. You are talking about something completely different to what you asked in the question to what is in the comments. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45330076/edit). No-one needs to trawl though a string of comments just to work out what you are actually asking. Look back on the comments and try to string that into a coherent example "within the question itself".